# Unable to drag n drop across a frame using Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drag-and-drop

I'm unable to drag an element (image) from the source to the target, across a frame. I have tried using with Webdriver (selenium 2.45.0) on Ubuntu, Chrome 41 and Windows Chrome 41 and Firefox 36.  Both WebElements can be successfully located independently so it's not a locator issue. My code:

```
    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    builder.clickAndHold(recipeImage);
    Action action = builder.build();
    action.perform();

    driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@id,'contentPane_view-')]")));

    builder = new Actions(driver);
    builder.moveToElement(imageField);
    builder.build();
    builder.release(imageField);
    action = builder.build();
    action.perform();
```

Comment: In lieu of any answers or suggestions, can anyone provide a working example of how to drag and drop the X symbol onto any one of the grid squares using the app below.  I have tried to no avail using Webdriver 2.45.0 and FF36: http://test.cita.illinois.edu/aria/draganddrop/draganddrop3.php